# C read string with fgets from 1 and keep 0 available for reading

Tags: c, string

I'm working on a function in C that gets a number from the user and converts it into a string, putting in the beginning of the string - + or nothing (if 0) than printing the length of the string and the string itself.

So lets say I enter "123", the string will contain: '+','1','2','3','\0'
and it will print: "The array length is 4 and it contain +123"
with minus it will print the same thing just with - at the beginning (-123) and with 0 it wont print any thing (0)

That is the code I made:

```
#define STRING_SIZE 100

int main ()
{
    int num;
    char sNum[STRING_SIZE] = {'\0'}, string[STRING_SIZE] = {'\0'};
    printf("%s", string);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    itoa(num, string, 10);

    if (num < 0) {
        sNum[0] = '-';
    }
    else if (num > 0) {
        sNum[0] = '+';
    }
    strncpy (sNum, string, STRING_SIZE);
    printf("\nThe string length is %d and contains the number: %s\n", strlen(sNum), sNum);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

And that is my output when I enter 123:

> The string length is 3 and contains the number: 123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You copy over the character you set in `sNum`. You need to copy beginning at the *second* character of `sNum`, i.e. `&sNum[1]`. Also remember to copy one less character from `string`. Also remember that there is a case where [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will not append the terminator.

Or just use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
snprintf(sNum, sizeof(sNum), "%+d", num);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strncpy (sNum,string,STRING_SIZE);
```

This overwrites the original value (with the sign).

Use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) instead, but make sure `sNum[1] == '\0'`.

Something like this:

```
char sNum[STRING_SIZE + 1] = {'\0'}, string[STRING_SIZE] = {'\0'};

// ...

if (num != 0) {
    sNum[0] = (num < 0) ? '-' : '+';    
}
strcat(sNum, string);
```

Comment: OP initializes `sNum` to all zeros with `char sNum[STRING_SIZE] = { '\0' }`, so `sNum[1] = 0;` line isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it to a string check this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int value;
    int length;
    if (scanf("%d%n", &value, &length) != 1)
        return -1;
    if (value == 0)
        printf("The string length is `1' and contains the number `0'\n");
    else
        printf("The string length is `%d' and contains the number `%+d'\n",
            length, value);
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

1. The `"%n"` specifier in `scanf()` stores in `length` the number of characters `scanf()` read.
2. The `printf()` `"+"` modifier adds a `+` in front of positive numbers and a `-` in front of negative numbers. The special value `0` is handled separately.
3. Always check the return value of `scanf()`.